# File "detect_main.py", line 8, in recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() AttributeError: module 'cv2' there no has attribute face

Tags: python, opencv

hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to run a program using python train_face.py

after recording to completion, then I run the command

python detect_main.py

but displays results like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqjj.jpg)

Comment: please review [ask]. no pictures of text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall:

pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

And if you usually use python IDLE then try to use programm like: PyCharm, etc.